# Push JSON to HTML page while page continues to load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, push

I am using ASP.NET and C# to build a page that processes several steps. I have another HTML page that originated the request to the ASP.NET page.

I am trying to figure out a way for the ASP.NET page to "push" status updates back to the HTML page via JSON at multiple steps throughout the ASP.NET. The HTML page would then receive the status update and update the user on what the ASP.NET page is doing. Such as (Step 1:Complete), (Step 2:Complete), etc.

My initial idea was that this might be accomplished by using something like Response.Flush().

I am using jQuery to handle and monitor my AJAX requests.

Comment: Http requests does not support "Push" request. client have to ask for it. So, using jquery and AJAX, ask the server for json elements as you go.

Comment: @devBinnooh I agree with you, it had to be client-side request.

Comment: Yep. Just trying to communicate the general idea I was after with this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* The client should be initiating the ajax request. The page cannot *push* to the client

Here's the general idea:

```
var onCompleteStep1 = function() {
    status.hide().html('Step 1 complete!').fadeIn();

    // first step complete, begin step 2
    $.ajax({
        success: onCompleteStep2
        ...
    });
};
var onCompleteStep2 = function() {
    status.hide().html('Step 2 complete!').fadeIn();

    // second step complete, begin step 3
    $.ajax({
        success: onCompleteStep3
        ...
    });
};
var onCompleteStep3 = function() {
    status.hide().html('Step 3 complete!').fadeIn();
};

// start up first step
$.ajax({
    success: onCompleteStep1
    ...
});
```

The idea is that the ajax success callback, you want to update the status text with your "Step 1:Complete)".

I made a simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YdQys/
The example simulates that ajax success callback by use of the buttons. But that is the general idea.